# Can't get isotope to fill the container width

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a client's web that uses isotope, it's currently working when I use it on a full-width container as seen here

https://constructionandrepair.com/#gallery

but attempting something similar, on a two-col layout doesn't seem to work as it doesn't take the whole width as seen here

https://constructionandrepair.com/devhome.html#gallery

here you can see a simple pen that shows the issue

https://codepen.io/camicase82-the-styleful/pen/ZExgRZg

as you can see, at first it loads in the right way for a second, then isotope re-arranges the elements in only 2 cols

My general Html structure is:

```
<div class="row">
      <!-- filter links -->
      <div class="newFiltering col-sm-3">
        <span class="full-width mb-35" data-filter='filterName'>filterName</span>
      </div>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>

      <!-- gallery -->
      <div class="newGallery text-center col-sm-9">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <div class="row">
        <!-- This one repeats lots of times -->
        <div class="col-md-4 newItems filterName">
          <div class="item-img">
            <img src="[[+image]]" alt="image">
            <div class="item-img-overlay valign">
              <div class="overlay-info full-width vertical-center">
                <h6>[[+name]]</h6>
                <p>[[+body]]</p>
              </div>
              <a href="[[+image]]" class="popimg">
                <i class="icofont icofont-image"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-fix"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

My initialization code is:

```
$('.newGallery').isotope({
      // options
      itemSelector: '.newItems',
      layoutMode: 'fitRows',
      percentPosition: true,
      masonry: {
        // use element for option
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
      }
      
    });

    var $newGallery = $('.gallery').isotope({
      // options
      
    });

    // filter items on button click
    $('.newFiltering').on( 'click', 'span', function() {

        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        $newGallery.isotope({ filter: filterValue });

    });

    $('.newFiltering').on( 'click', 'span', function() {

        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    });
```

The thing that got me scratching my head, is that it actually organizes the images as it should before isotope loads, I mean it shows 3 cols for a sec, then goes to 2

Comment: Could you make a snippet that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: @Behrouz thanks for answering, here you can see a pen with the issue https://codepen.io/camicase82-the-styleful/pen/ZExgRZg as you can see in this case all elements are in a single column opposite to at least 3

Comment: So, if there are only one or two elements, you want those elements to take up 100% of the width of the container?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was related to the structure, since the newGallery selector used by isotope had an additional row before the actual items, it was calculating the width based on the wrong element, the solution was to add the selector to the same level of the internal row, and it started working as expected, the final solution can be seen here

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <h2>Col izq</h2>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-9">
      <!-- Here we define the actual grid -->
      <div class="grid row">
       <div class="grid-sizer col-4"></div>
       <div class="grid-item col-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/camicase82-the-styleful/pen/ZExgRZg

The issue was clarified by [isotope team](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/1633)